# Session Authentication Mode is not working in Moxie manager when using with TinyMCE with new version of Moxiemanager in .NET

Tags: tinymce, editor, text-editor, image-uploading

I had a new version of Moxiemanager. I have a requirement of setting custom path using specific User Id. 
There is procedure of setting

In Web.Config
and Setting custom path on page load or login like this
 **HttpContext.Current.Session["moxiemanager.storage.path"] = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Tinmce_data_Member/Member/20");**

But I dont't know why this is not working. I can see images using the path specified but thumbnail do not appear,even there is problem with uploading file.
This works fine with old version of TinyMCe or if don't use Session.
Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the logged in session object?

```
Session["isLoggedIn"] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The  issue is fixed now and it was due to the reason that there was error in Moxie manager and they have fixed up the issue in new version.